VueJs 3 Composition defineEmits with TypeScript
I have a component with the following emits definition
<script lang="ts" setup>
import formInput from "@/core/Store/form-input.ts";
import { FormInputEmits } from "@/types/Form.ts";

defineProps<{
  modelValue: string | number,
  type?: string,
  error?: string
}>();

const emit = defineEmits<FormInputEmits<string | number>>();

const { input, inputFocus, update } = formInput<HTMLInputElement>(emit);

defineExpose({ focus: inputFocus });
</script>

<template>
  <input
    ref="input"
    :class="['sm:text-sm rounded placeholder:text-base-400', {
      'border-base-300 focus:border-primary-500 focus:ring-primary-500': !error,
      'border-red-300 focus:border-red-500 focus:ring-red-500': !!error,
    }]"
    :type="type || 'text'"
    :value="modelValue"
    @input="update"
  />
</template>

The interface it implements uses Generic with default value and then passes it to the payload:
export interface FormInputEmits<T = string | number | boolean> {
  'update:modelValue': [payload: T]
}

When I try to compile it with vite:vue I'm getting the following error:

[vite:vue] Name in a signature must be an Identifier, ObjectPattern or ArrayPattern, instead got AssignmentPattern. (234:29)

What's even more strange is that when I use the object literal as type instead of the interface - it seem to work fine:
const emit = defineEmits<{ "update:modelValue": [payload: string | number] }>();

Any pointers as to why this isn't a valid approach?

Please, provide a way to reproduce, it's specific to your setup. Code is correct and cannot reproduce the problem in general

Thanks @EstusFlask. It's going to be rather difficult as it's all part of a large system. Anything in particular you think I should check to try and narrow it down? I'm updating the code to include the entire component.

No, I'm unaware of such problem. The error comes from a parser, it's low level and may not be directly tied to the perceived purpose of the code. "Assignment" could refer to "=" in a generic being incorrectly parsed or caused by the deps. Could be outdated or incompatible deps. If it's specific to package versions you use, you may be  able to reproduce this with helloworld app that's based on your current setup

I just found out what was causing it and it was quite literally not connected to the actual code that it was breaking.
It was another interface that I've wrongly associated the null with instead of defining it as one of the types for the argument:
fields: (field_id: string, group_id: string = null) => Promise<AxiosResponse>

instead of the correct way:
fields: (field_id: string, group_id: string | null) => Promise<AxiosResponse>

